# How do I create a star-rating system?

Tags: asp.net, frontend

Amazon has a star rating system. Other sites use smiley faces that change color when you mouse over them. Does anyone know of an API I can get or a simple way to put this together?

This is an ASP.NET 2010 app.

Answer (score 3):

Have a read of this:

http://imar.spaanjaars.com/410/building-a-simple-rating-control-for-aspnet-20

Answer (score 3):

Presuming it is ASP.NET web-forms you could try using [the Rating control](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Rating/Rating.aspx) in the Ajax Control Tookit. Or you could check out [Building a Simple Rating Control for ASP.NET 2.0 tutorial](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/410/building-a-simple-rating-control-for-aspnet-20) which guides you through all the steps. If you'd rather go the jQuery root then there are [plugins](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/) to do this, though the back-end data capture and storage would be a bit more tricky in web-forms.

Answer (score 2):

There are many Star Rating available as controls. From [microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163861.aspx) or  [codeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/cs_star_rating_control.aspx)

or [css Jquery](http://www.billb.name/it/Star-Rating-CSS-JQuery.asp) etc. try  Binging/googling it :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Telerik](http://telerik.com) has a nice one, if you are looking for commercial software (as opposed to free stuff)

Answer (score 0):

i believe you need to look for javascript to solve this...

you can check:

http://speckyboy.com/2010/04/21/15-javascript-and-plugins-and-tutorials-for-adding-ratings/